# How do I get the type of a record in Clojurescript?

Tags: clojurescript

I have two records in Clojurescript defined as follows:

```
(defrecord Html [])
(defrecord Tree [])
```

I need to find out the type of the item which can be defined as either of these records, how can I do this?

```
(def a (Html.))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(defrecord Html [])
(defrecord Tree [])

(= (type (->Html)) Html) ; true
(= (type (->Html)) Tree) ; false

(= (type (->Tree)) Html) ; false
(= (type (->Tree)) Tree) ; true
```

Answer (score 2):

The best, host-independent way to do it is:

```
(instance? Html a)
```

This will work for any type.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I solved it like this and it seems to work:

```
(defrecord Html [])
(defrecord Tree [])



(defprotocol TypeInfo
  (gettype [this] nil)
)


(extend-type Html
  TypeInfo
  (gettype [this]  "Html")

)

(extend-type Tree
  TypeInfo
  (gettype [this]  "Tree")

)

(def a (Html.))


(gettype a)

(def b (Tree.))


(gettype b)
```